# Typescript and Javascript React-Icons className conflict(Self-answer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, components

I was using React in Javascript and recently switch to NextJs with Typescript

I import react-icons this BiUser just as usual like in react but in react even if adding className in icons works well but in Typescript it gives error

*Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconBaseProps'.
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconBaseProps'.*

This is the black of code. (I use tailwind)

```
<BiUser className='text-light w-[35px] h-[35px]'/>
```

However, what skeptical about this is that even if i ignore that error, the className works just like what I am expect it to do, just that error I want to have solution, do i just ignore it or I have to do something or just get rid my way of adding className to components

I tried adding className to components just like how i do in react, but it throws error in Typescript

However it does the same exact thing i expect it to do, just that it throws error

See answer below:

Comment: Do you get this error for any component or just react-icon components?

Comment: @Designly I created a component Test and imported it to my index.tsx, adding the same className and it also says the same however it only says in component "type IntrinsicAttritubutes does not exist"

I kinda have an idea why this problem persist as i think that Typescript knows that it is component and not a DOM elements even tho it return DOM elements(JSX) 

so for my problem above, I solved it by adding the default attributes by react-icons and just avoid doing my old way of adding className

Comment: I removed solved from the title. Please consider adding a self-answer with your solution instead.

Comment: @JamesRisner Great, Thank you and sorry.

Comment: Thank you for improving your posts. I also removed self answer from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using the className in components even though it is properly working in React Javascript and Typescript( but in typescript case, it throws error even though it works) and just use the preferred attributes that the typescript accepts for IconBaseProps.